# Binding StackLayout to ViewModel doens't work

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, stacklayout

I would like to have a property in my ViewModel that is linked to my StackLayout. I tried this by Binding my StackLyout to the ViewModel.

When I click on a button, this layout should be made invisible.

When I do this with the code below, my program crashes with a NulReferenceObject: Object Reference not set to an instance of an object. The StackLayout that i am talking about is the first one in the code below.

```
<FlexLayout>
    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{Binding CreateQuizPageQuizNameSL}"> // This StackLayout should be bind to the ViewModel
        <Label Text="Create New Quiz" />
        <StackLayout >
            <Entry Text="{Binding QuizNameInput}" Placeholder="Enter quiz name"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <Button Command="{Binding SubmitCreateQuizCommand}" Text="Create my quiz now!"></Button>
</FlexLayout>
```

**ViewModel**

```
internal class CreateQuizPageViewModel
{
    // Quiz Name Input
    public String QuizNameInput { get; set; }

    // Command submit creating a quiz
    public Command SubmitCreateQuizCommand { get; set; }

    public StackLayout CreateQuizPageQuizNameSL { get; set; } = new StackLayout();

    public CreateQuizPageViewModel()
    {
        // Declaring a new command, giving the OnSubmitCreateNewQuizClick to the delegate
        SubmitCreateQuizCommand = new Command(OnSubmitCreateNewQuizClick);
    }

    // When a user submit the creation of new quiz
    public void OnSubmitCreateNewQuizClick()
    {
        CreateQuizPageQuizNameSL.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `CreateQuizPageQuizNameSL` is declared in your VM but never instantiated so it is always null.

Comment: @Jason If I initialize my StackLayout as a new StackLayout (`public StackLayout CreateQuizPageQuizNameSL { get; set; } = new StackLayout();`), I don't get the crash, but that way I lose my StackLayout. A new instance is being created, which I don't want.

Comment: its not really clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Having `View` objects in your VM goes against the idea of MVVM.  And you don't appear to be using BindableLayouts as intended.  You typically define a template and apply it to each element in the Layout's ItemsSource, which you aren't even using.  If all you want is to control the visibility of your Layout, all you need to do is bind the `IsVisible` property

Comment: What i would like to accomplish: when a user clicks on a button, follow method is executed: `OnSubmitCreateNewQuizClick()`. This method should remove the StackLayout i'm trying to bind in order to replace it in the future by another StackLayout. The problem is that the `OnSubmitCreateNewQuizClick()` method is executed in the VM, so i need a reference to the StackLayout that is present in the .xaml file, which i don't have for the moment

Comment: I'd suggest having the VM raise an event that the View then responds to in order to add/modify/delete content

Comment: As Jason suggests, the VM should just tell the view that a change is needed. In the view, you could use a datatemplateselector to switch between different layouts. Or sometimes its as simple as having both layouts in the xaml, with one hidden (IsVisible=false). Then change which one is visible.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i fixed it the way you explained it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to switch two layouts using `IsVisible` binding.

FIRST Add `Nuget Xamarin.CommunityToolkit` to your Xamarin Forms project. (The one that is "MyProjectName", without ".iOS" or ".Android" at end.)

TwoLayoutPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBugs"
                 x:Class="TestBugs.TwoLayoutPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:TwoLayoutViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <xct:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout 
                    IsVisible="{Binding UseSecondLayout, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}}"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label Text="First Layout" FontSize="20" />
                <Button Text="To Second" Command="{Binding SwitchToSecondLayoutCommand}" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding UseSecondLayout}"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label Text="Second Layout!" FontSize="32" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

TwoLayoutViewModel.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestBugs
{
    public class TwoLayoutViewModel : BindableObject
    {
        private bool _usesecondLayout = false;
        public bool UseSecondLayout {
            get => _usesecondLayout;
            set {
                _usesecondLayout = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        public TwoLayoutViewModel()
        {
            SwitchToSecondLayoutCommand = new Command(SwitchToSecondLayout);
        }


        public Command SwitchToSecondLayoutCommand { get; set; }


        private void SwitchToSecondLayout()
        {
            UseSecondLayout = true;
        }
    }
}
```